# bug fix after migration to drupal 10 (AssertionError: Cannot load the "entity_browser" entity with NULL ID.)

Tags: drupal

I upgraded my project to drupal 10, I have a problem:

When I want to filter in the media view, change the page, this does not work here is my error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXlDm.png)
AssertionError: Cannot load the "entity_browser" entity with NULL ID. in assert() (line 261 of /var/www/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).

I don't really know where to intervene if it comes from my function load , from a module  or from a custom theme

```
here is my function load:
**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function load($id) {
assert(!is_null($id), sprintf('Cannot load the "%s" entity with NULL ID.', $this->entityTypeId));
$entities = $this->loadMultiple([$id]);
return $entities[$id] ?? NULL;
}
```

how can i fix this bug?

I am a junior dev, on this project I tried to make a patch, I found nothing conclusive on the net. I don't know how to intervene to solve the problem